# <ons-page>でのスクロールバーの表示

Tags: onsen-ui

onsen-uiの`<ons-page>`を使用すると、ページが１画面以上ある場合もスクロールバーが表示されないのですが、表示させるにはどのような方法があるでしょうか？

※onsen-uiをスマホ/PCのレスポンシブで製作を行っております。
　スマホの場合はスクロールバーがなくてもよいのですが、PCの場合は、ユーザビリティの観点でスクロールバーを表示させたいと考えております。